# Laravel AVG not returning the right value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, aggregate-functions, average

I'm trying to use the aggregate `AVG()` to return the average of a query.

When I do

```
$values = Model::orderBy('columnA', 'desc')
    ->select('value')
    ->where('ColumnB', '50')
    ->where('ColumnC', '<=','10')
    ->Take(5)
    ->get()

$arr = array_flatten($values)

//returns array(78, 73, 81, 83, 74)
//Average roughly to 77.8
```

**My goal is to reach this average of 77.8**

However, when I change `get()` to `avg('value')`

```
$values = Model::orderBy('columnA', 'desc')
        ->select('value')
        ->where('ColumnB', '50')
        ->where('ColumnC', '<=','10')
        ->Take(5)
        ->avg('value')

//Returns 69.5
```

I noticed that I can remove the `take()` it does not change the value returned by `avg()` which is odd because I have more than 5 records that correspond to this query. My guess is that the average is calculated on a larger number of rows that I want.

**How can I easily make the average on the values that are returned by my first query?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVG() is aggregate function that takes no LIMIT param, thus Builder's take(5) method has no effect here.

You can run avg on a subquery that retrieves only 5 rows:

```
$subquery = Model::select('value')
    ->whereRaw('ColumnB = 50')
    ->whereRaw('ColumnC <= 10')
    ->Take(5)
    ->toSql();

$average = DB::table(DB::raw(" ($subquery) as sub "))->avg('value');
```

Comment: This totally make sense! Thanks a lot. However, when I apply this I got a `Null` from `$average`. When I try to `get()` it, `$average` returns an empty array. I checked and my subquery is fine (`$subquery` returns the values in the question if I use `get()` instead of `toSql()`).

Comment: please run and paste DB::getQueryLog() to check the queries, as it should work flawlessly

Comment: Actually, it worked. I missed the `WhereRaw` at first read. 

Thanks!